# When do fruits and vegetables need Hechser for being bug free

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, contemporary-halacha, bugs

When and which fruits and vegetables need a Hechser for being bug free (which is necessary in kashrut). Sources for the Halacha please